# SQL Pivot row to column?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012, pivot

My table looks like this

[image]

i want to pivot the rows into table heads.

if i use:

```
 SELECT [USER],[DIVISION], [COMPANY],[RIGHTS] FROM
  (SELECT [USER],[ATTRIBUTE],[VALUE],[RIGHTS] FROM [AGDA_MANUAL].[dbo].[TEST] WHERE [PROC] = 'FINANCE' ) AS  T1
  PIVOT (MAX([VALUE]) FOR [ATTRIBUTE] IN ([DIVISION],[COMPANY])) AS T2
```

[image]

And this is **almost** what i want

but is there a way to NOT use the MAX in the pivot? im loosing DIVSION 010 AND COMPANY 1 for DOMAIN\USER1 when i use the MAX ??.

can any one help me here?

****UPDATE*************

I was missing one column i needed because i was going to end up with more rows(as one of you said).

[image]

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2012

Comment: Could you clarify what output you want given your sample data?

Comment: You really need to be much more detailed about what you're trying to do here, at present it's both ambiguous and/or appears that your model may be incomplete.  Specifically, what *should* the results for User1 be?  I can see ***four*** combinations of Division and Company for User1; `023, 1` and `023, 2` and `010, 1` and `010, 2`.  All happen to have `admin` rights, but you give no indication what to do if one or more rows had a different value in `rights`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that pivot needs some way to connect the DIVISION and COMPANY data.
MAX allows it to do so - otherwise how does it know which COMPANY is connected with which DIVISION.
One solution to this would be to add an artificial column (Generated via `RowNumber()`) that you would add to the grouping (along with PROC & USER)
You would still need to decide if DIV 023 belongs with COMP 1,2 or 3

You could end up with something like

```
FINANCE | DOMAIN\USER1 | 1 | DIVISION | 023
FINANCE | DOMAIN\USER1 | 2 | DIVISION | 010
FINANCE | DOMAIN\USER1 | 1 | COMPANY  | 1
FINANCE | DOMAIN\USER1 | 2 | COMPANY  | 2
FINANCE | DOMAIN\USER2 | 1 | COMPANY  | 3
```

Now you can pivot and have Company & DIVISION as columns on the Same Row